# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient null reference exception when connecting to Azure SQL database from Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I'm getting the exception below when making a connection with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to an Azure SQL server from an Azure Function App.

All else equal it works when testing locally, but when deploying the app we get the below exception.

I've checked the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" option under networking on the SQL server. Are the any other configuration I need to make to access the SQL server/database from a function app.

Any advice is much appreciated.

**Connection string**

I use the connection string from the Azure portal for Azure AD authentication:

Server=tcp:{0},1433;Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={2};Password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Password';

##### Exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.SendFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthToken fedAuthToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
```

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is linked to this issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1737. AAD must report that the user is "federated". If it reports that the user is "managed", then IWA doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I took a sample code of Azure Functions which fetch the data from Azure SQL Server and have tried practically. This is working good with the below steps:

**Created SQL Database and allowed these settings by going to Set Server Firewall option**:

[image]

[image]

**Running Locally**:

[image]

**Note**: Add the Azure SQL Connection String in Azure Function App > Configuration > Add Connection String

[image]

**Running in Azure**:

[image]

**Please find the code and the SQL Commands used above from my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/DelliganeshS-MT/AzFuncSQLProject)**.